# EF Core - Add constraint on multiple properties that one of them is required but not all

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-5.0

I have a class with some properties and I want to define a constraint on two properties (int type),
that one of them is required but not both.
In SQL it will like this:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> CHECK
((<first_field> IS NOT NULL AND <second_field> IS NULL) OR
(<second_field> IS NOT NULL AND <first_field> IS NULL))
```

Is it possible with FluentAPI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [HasCheckConstraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.hascheckconstraint?view=efcore-5.0), eg

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(p => p.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasCheckConstraint("ck_NameOrDescription", $"Name is not null or Description is not null");
```

Comment: To get exactly what I wanted, I changed to: $"Name is not null and Description is null or Description is not null and Name is null", thanks.